# What is the perfect replace of toInclude() assertion in expect new version?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Stuck with this.I am trying to test my login API using expect and new version of expect throwing me some error.
That's my testing code.

```js
it('should login user and return auth token', (done) => {
        request(app)
        .post('/users/login')
        .send({
            email : users[1].email,
            password : users[1].password
        })
        .expect((res) => {
            expect(res.headers['x-auth']).toBeTruthy();
        })
        .end((error,res) => {
            if(error)
            {
                return done(error);
            }
            User.findById(users[1]._id).then((user) => {
                expect(user.tokens[0]).toMatchObject({
                    access : 'auth',
                    token : res.headers['x-auth']
                });
                done();
            }).catch((error) => done(error));
        });
        
    });
```

And error is

```js
1) POST /users/login
       should login user and return auth token:
     Error: expect(received).toMatchObject(expected)

Expected value to match object:
  {"access": "auth", "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1OWYwMzM0ZGExMzRmYjFmNzg4NTkzOTciLCJhY2Nlc3MiOiJhdX
RoIiwiaWF0IjoxNTA4OTE0MDEzfQ.S0KCmLADcCLPWTK1khxNPO03tVMTW0HU117xapm56MM"}
Received:
  {"_id": "59f0335da134fb1f788593b3", "access": "auth", "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1OWYwMzM0ZGExMzR
mYjFmNzg4NTkzOTciLCJhY2Nlc3MiOiJhdXRoIiwiaWF0IjoxNTA4OTE0MDEzfQ.S0KCmLADcCLPWTK1khxNPO03tVMTW0HU117xapm56MM"}
Difference:
- Expected
+ Received

  Object {
+   "_id": "59f0335da134fb1f788593b3",
    "access": "auth",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1OWYwMzM0ZGExMzRmYjFmNzg4NTkzOTciLCJhY2Nlc3MiOiJhdXRoIiwiaWF0IjoxNTA
4OTE0MDEzfQ.S0KCmLADcCLPWTK1khxNPO03tVMTW0HU117xapm56MM",
  }
```

I am testing two things but the code itself including _id and showing me that error. In previous version of expect (when Jest was not introduced) it was simple using toInclude() assertion,but now both toContain() and toMatchObject() showing same error.

That's my seed file

```js
const{ObjectID} = require('mongodb');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const {Todo} = require('./../../models/todo');
const {User} = require('./../../models/user');

const userOneId = new ObjectID();
const userTwoId = new ObjectID();
const users = [{
    _id: userOneId,
    email: 'adil.aj95@gmail.com',
    password : 'userOnePass',
    tokens: [{
        access : 'auth',
        token : jwt.sign({_id : userOneId,access : 'auth'}, 'abc123').toString()
    }]

},
{
    _id: userTwoId,
    email: 'adil2.aj95@gmail.com',
    password : 'userTwoPass',
    // tokens: [{
    //     access : 'auth',
    //     token : jwt.sign({_id : userTwoId,access : 'auth'}, 'abc123').toString()
    // }]


}];
```

Comment: Every time it will generate new object id and u won't be able to match entire object. instead of `toMatchObject` why don't u check `access` and `token` individually once u received the response.

Answer (score 2):

You need just a slight change. Instead of using

```js
expect(user.tokens[0]).toMatchObject({
    access : 'auth',
    token : res.headers['x-auth']
});
```

include `.toObject()` after `user` like this

```js
expect(user.toObject().tokens[0]).toMatchObject({
    access : 'auth',
    token : res.headers['x-auth']
});
```

Why? Your `user` is a mongoose object that has more info than you would expect. You can see that there is an extra `_id` property in the `token` (the error that is thrown shows that). What `toObject()` does is it returns just the object as you would expect it, without all the mongoose-specific properties (stuff like `_id`, `__v` etc).

Comment: In _"expect": "^23.6.0"_  you don't need to use .toObject() because **.toMatchObject(object)** compares the key value pairs you pass as argument in an object with the same key value pairs within the Object you are trying to compare with, so if this last one has more information doesn't matter.
[https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tomatchobjectobject]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toHaveProperty(keyPath, value)` for the new expect version by jest.

So the code becomes like this:

```
expect(user.tokens[0]).toHaveProperty('access', 'auth');
expect(user.tokens[0]).toHaveProperty('token', user.tokens[0].token);
```